# How do actions that trigger on a certain movement die result work when rolling two dice?

Tags: talisman

Some cards have things happen when you roll a certain result on the movement die. For instance, the [Troll](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Troll) has the option of regenerating:

> Whenever you roll a 6 for your move, you may *regenerate* instead of moving. If you choose to regenerate, heal one life and your turn immediately ends.

The [Grim Reaper](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Grim_Reaper) works this way too, moving when a 1 is rolled, and other cards such as [Rumour of Riches](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Rumour_of_Riches_(Adventure)) and [Flying Carpet](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Flying_Carpet) also have an effect trigger this way.

But how does this work if you roll two dice for movement? For instance, the [Riding Horse](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Riding_Horse):

> You may roll 2 dice and add them together to determine how far you can move.

Or the [Torch](http://www.talismanwiki.com/Torch):

> You may roll two dice for your movement in the Dungeon and choose one of the results to use for your move.

How do abilities that trigger based on the result of the movement die happen when either die has the value?

Answer (score 1):

You have to roll a 6 for your movement in order to be able to regenerate instead of moving. If you have Riding horse then you roll 2 dice for movement. If one of the two is a 6 you can regenerate instead as long as you control the Troll.

Comment: So to clarify, it doesn't matter if you roll two dice and add them together (like the Riding Horse) or roll two dice and pick one (like the Torch), you still get to trigger abilities like the Troll's regeneration if one of the dice is the number you want?

Answer (score 0):

For the Horse: If one of the dice displays a six you will regenerate health if you have the troll.

For the dungeon: The dice you pick is the one you use so that one would have to be a six if you wanted to regenerate health with the troll.

So:
Pick a die: that die will trigger all available triggered abilities which require a number on the die.
Two dice: The dice will trigger the available triggered abilities which will trigger on a die number if one or both of them have the desired number